# How to find the textbox position using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get the text box position using the JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the script

```
document.getElementById("<textboxId>").offsetTop

document.getElementById("<textboxId>").offsetLeft
```

Comment: if i use the script it shows the error  "document.getElementById("txtSentto45") is null"

Comment: Do you have textbox with id txtSentto45 in your page? [please check you might have txtSentto45 as text box name not id]

Comment: Yes i had the textbox with the id  "txtSentto45".Your Code is working Fine . if i run the code means i get replay 2 or 3 ,now i need the exact position .example top =322px. Is It possible